# Error using eps ..... Class must be 'single' or 'double'

Tags: matlab

I'm facing a problem with my code which is the error (using eps ..... Class must be 'single' or 'double'). which due to the following code line

```
beta=sqrt  (  (0.5*nthroot((Tt + (sqrt(-Delta/27))),3)) + ...
     (0.5*nthroot((Tt - (sqrt(-Delta/27))),3)) -(1/3*T)  );
```

Comment: I don't see eps in there nor do you define what your other variables are.  Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`nthroot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html) makes a call to the function [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) in its code, passing it the class of a variable which should have the same class as your first input argument to `nthroot`. As the documentation for `nthroot` specifies, it only supports `single` and `double` precision inputs, so your first argument to the function likely isn't one of those (my guess is it's probably an [integer type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html), so you will have to convert to [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) or [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html)).

Comment: thank you for the answer. however, I think if i give you the values of the Tt and Delta the will make it easier for you to see where is the problem exactly...... Tt=24747...../646......(very long numbers) & Delta= -658...../4512..... (very long numbers as well)

Comment: @SandLand: The *value* of the numbers isn't my concern, it's the *type*. What do you get when you call `class(Tt)` or `class(Delta)`? Are they symbolic variables?

Comment: both of them 'sym'

Comment: @SandLand: There's your problem. They are symbolic objects. If they only contain numeric values, you can convert them by doing `Tt=double(Tt);`.